# Advertencia: mysqli_query () espera al menos 2 parámetros, 1 dado

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Tengo el siguiente codigo php el cual consulta en la base de datos el campo usuario para mostrar al usuario si este esta disponible o no por medio de ajax.
Mi problema es que mi conexion esta con PDO en un archivo en otra carpeta entonces al utilizar MySQLi me pide 2 parametros pero no se como traer la variable de conexion hasta mi php de chequear en la base de datos.

El codigo:

Conexion
Nombre Archivo: conexion.php

```
    <?php
class Conexion{
  public function conectar(){
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=restaurante","root","1234");
    return $link;

  }

}
?>

Este es mi Archivo check.php

    <?php

include("../../models/conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST["usuario_registro"])) {

  $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario = '".$_POST["usuario_registro"]."'");
  $result = mysqli_query($sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    echo '<span class="text-danger">El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso.</span>';
  }else {
    echo '<span class="text-danger">El nombre de usuario es correcto</span>';
  }

}
 ?>
```

Al teclear el usuario me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Dev.Joel no es exactamente un duplicado, fíjate que él está usando PDO: `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=restaurante","root","1234");`, por lo tanto aquí el problema es que hay una mezcla de APIs, porque luego en el resto del código él intenta usar `mysqli`. El OP debería decirnos por qué si intenta crear un objeto PDO, luego para las consultas usa mysqli habiendo además puesto dicha etiqueta a la pregunta.

Comment: Es porque mysqli_query espera dos parametros y solo le estás pasando uno: el primer parametro debe ser la conexión a mysql y el segundo sí es el query mira la documentación de php  hay varios ejemplos de uso de mysqli http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Si entiendo pero como obtengo la variable de la conexion si esta en otro archivo php

Comment: No uses la conexión del otro archivo (no sabria decirte si la conección hecha con PDO es consumible por mysqli_query), deberías  hacer la conexión con mysqli_connect en el mismos archivo: `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`  
       despues si puedes usar:  `mysqli_query($link, $query);`